# Animate New data in Google line charts

Tags: javascript, animation, google-visualization, linechart

I am making an line chart that will have lines appear and disappear with user interaction. Is there a way to animate the added data like the chart startup animation? Or fade line in and out so that it isn't so abrupt?

One Idea I had was to to set the new data to 0 then have have it animate to the new data but was wondering if there was another way.

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

to animate from one data set to another, redraw the same chart with new data.

see following, working snippet. the data in each column is "swapped" before redraw...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["PR","CE","PE"],["5500",1875,2025],["6000",61500,104775],["6100",450,13725],["6500",35400,421800],["6600",150,121950],["6700",600,770925],["6800",13650,370425],["6900",33375,586650],["7000",744375,1122075],["7100",229200,355875],["7200",199800,689850],["7300",461550,244425],["7400",442950,439125],["7500",835350,484725],["7600",459000,82800],["7700",482250,48000],["7800",893250,11550],["7900",1215600,13500],["8000",741150,93525],["8100",242325,6150],["8200",326175,1500],["8300",365850,75],["8500",104850,2925],["9000",13050,11775]]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    var options = {
      animation: {
        startup: true,
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear'
      }
    };

    var redrawTimes = 0;
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'animationfinish',function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        var swap1 = data.getValue(i, 2);
        var swap2 = data.getValue(i, 1);
        data.setValue(i, 1, swap1);
        data.setValue(i, 2, swap2);
      }
      if (redrawTimes < 5) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          chart.draw(data, options);
          redrawTimes++;
        }, 2000);
      }
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add data to your `DataTable` and the call `.draw()` on your chart again, using `options` which contains the animation settings.

Options could look like

```
var options = {
  animation: {
    duration: 600
  }
};
```

And then just call `chart.draw(DataTable, options)` to animate it.

See example live [at codepen](http://codepen.io/heennkkee/pen/PzKvBX?editors=0010j). Just add data with the button and it'll smoothly be added to the line.